# Apache Solr results using stopwords and eDismax

Tags: search

On our drupal multilingual system we use apache Solr 3.5. 
The problem is known on different blogs, sites I read. 
The search results are not the one we want. 
On our code in hook apachesolr_query_alter we override the defaultOperator:  $query->replaceParam('mm', '90%'); 
The requirement is, 
a) when I search for: biological analyses, I want to fetch only the results which have both of the words. 
b) When I search for: biological and chemical analyses, I want it to fetch only the results which have all the words, that is, biological , chemical, analyses. The and is not indexed due to stopwords.

If I set mm to 100% and my query has stopwords(example b) it will not fetch any result.
If I set mm to 100$ and my query does not have stopwords(example a) it will fetch the desired results. 
If I set mm anything between 50%-99% it fetches not wanted results, as results that contain only one of the searched keywords (or words **like** the searched keywords, like analyse (even if I searched for analyses and not analyse)).

If I search using + before the words that are mandatory it works ok, but it is not user friendly, to ask from the user to type + before each word except from the stopwords.

Do I make any sense?

Below are some of our configuration details:

All the indexed fields are of type text_[language], 
e.g from our schema.xml

```
<field name="label" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true" omitNorms="true"/>
<field name="i18n_label_en" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true" omitNorms="true"/>
<field name="i18n_label_fr" type="text_fr" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true" omitNorms="true"/>
All the text fieldtypes have the same configuration except from the protected, words, dictionary parameters which are language specific.
```

e.g from our schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent_en.txt"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1" splitOnNumerics="1" stemEnglishPossessive="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/><filter class="solr.DictionaryCompoundWordTokenFilterFactory" dictionary="compoundwords_en.txt" minWordSize="5" minSubwordSize="4" maxSubwordSize="15" onlyLongestMatch="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords_en.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent_en.txt"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms_en.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1" splitOnNumerics="1" stemEnglishPossessive="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/><filter class="solr.DictionaryCompoundWordTokenFilterFactory" dictionary="compoundwords_en.txt" minWordSize="5" minSubwordSize="4" maxSubwordSize="15" onlyLongestMatch="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords_en.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

 <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>
```

solrconfig.xml

```
 <requestHandler name="pinkPony" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="defType">edismax</str>
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <bool name="omitHeader">true</bool>
      <float name="tie">0.01</float>

      <int name="timeAllowed">${solr.pinkPony.timeAllowed:-1}</int>
      <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>


      <str name="spellcheck">false</str>

      <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">false</str>

      <str name="spellcheck.count">1</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

Indexing stopwords, isn't an option for us. Is there a workaround found?
ANY ideas are appreciated!